# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets'

Tags: flutter, dart

i have an error when im trying to run my flutter app. I've tryied with flutter run and i've selected de device, but this messages shows in the terminal:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets'.

> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file 'C:\flutter_project\cursin2\LoginFlutter-master\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out'

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: run flutter clean please

Comment: i've tryied with flutter clean, but doesnt work :/

Comment: If you are using VSCode, try removing any kotlin extensions and then running. As stated in this thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59975.

Comment: i dont have any kotlin extensions, do you know where can i found it?

Comment: i have this in build.gradle buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

Answer (score 0):

I try this on Visual Code

```
    Update the Android Studio to the latest
    Remove the kotlin plugin in Visual studio code
```

or you need to run `flutter clean build`
then it will show some error to fix that you need to package get your `pubspec.yaml` file for that you need to run `futter pub get` on the terminal then you need to close vs code and reopen it and run your application again now can see your application run without any issue